# Get the XY position of the caret in TextArea

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, textarea, flash-builder

I need to get the XY position of the caret in textArea.

I already found a way to get the Y, but i dont know how to get X, can anyone help?

If any1 want to know, this is how i get Y:

```
var textBeforeCaret:String = text.substr(0, caretIndex);
var textDump:String = this.text;
this.text = textBeforeCaret;
this.validateNow();
yVariable = this.textHeight;
this.text = textDump;
```

Comment: Did you try getCharBoundaries() with the character before and/or after the caret? http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#getCharBoundaries()

Comment: The problem is that i need to get the substring from the textfield end of line (not just when i press ENTER) to my end caret, but that is a bit problematic, because it isnt marked with \r

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627185/get-caret-position-x-y-in-input-textfield-as3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking the link from RafH, i did this:

```
var popUpX:int = 0;
var popUpY:int = 0;
if(text.length > 0){

if(caretIndex > 0){
                                if(this.textField.getCharBoundaries(caretIndex -1) != null){
popUpX = this.textField.getCharBoundaries(caretIndex - 1).right;
popUpY = this.textField.getCharBoundaries(caretIndex - 1).bottom;
}
else{
popUpX = 0;
var i:int = 2;
                                    while(this.textField.getCharBoundaries(caretIndex - i) == null && caretIndex - i > -1){
i++;
}
if(caretIndex - i > -1){
popUpY = this.textField.getCharBoundaries(caretIndex - i).bottom + i * 10;
}
else{
popUpY = i * 10;
}
}
}
else{
popUpX = this.textField.getCharBoundaries(caretIndex).right;
popUpY = this.textField.getCharBoundaries(caretIndex).bottom;
}
}
else{
popUpX = 0;
popUpY = 0;
}
```

it isnt perfect, but its good enough for me