# Flex limit number of characters in textarea

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, textarea

Possible this asked before but not get any proper answer for that.

```
<s:TextArea fontSize="14" heightInLines="15" widthInChars="40" />
```

I have textarea where i want to limit(allow) **max 15 lines** user can enter not more than that. 
I tried to find out any property available or try to do with programming but, didn't get what i won't.

On text change tried to find out number of lines but, didn't succeed.

```
var textLength:Number = event.currentTarget.text.length; //It gives length of text.
```

I also want to limit **max 40 character in single line**. Then after user entered any text then go to below line. 
Is that possible?

Any help would greatly appreciated.

**Edit:**

I have limit line number like following way:

```
protected function onKeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if(txtArea.textFlow.flowComposer.numLines > txtArea.heightInLines && event.keyCode == Keyboard.ENTER)
    {
        txtArea.text = txtArea.text.substr(0, txtArea.selectionActivePosition-1) + txtArea.text.substr(txtArea.selectionActivePosition, txtArea.text.length);
    } 
}
```

But, still can't limit 40 character per line. How can i give limit for particular line?

Comment: Don't know why people downvote the questions. Is that low quality?

Answer (score 0):

This is simply to custom logic to be already implemented for you. You have to do it yourself.

Listen for the text input event

```
input.addEventListener(TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT, onInput);
```

in that handler, prevent the default behaviour and perform the desired logic to set the `text` property to the result you want.

```
private function onInput(e:TextEvent):void
{     
    e.preventDefault();

    trace("current text: " + e.target.text);
    trace("inserted text: " + e.text);

    // perform logic here

    e.target.text = "result";
}
```

In your case, the logic is likely achieved most conveniently with a regex pattern that matches up to 40 groups of up to 15 characters plus a line break.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I know this way i can get current and inserted text. But, how can i get in inserted line total how much character is there? In which line i am going to enter. so, i can prevent if it goes more than 15

Comment: That's explained in the last paragraph of my answer.

Comment: Can you show me any example? I can not get current line where i am going to enter text.

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12627185/4347580